# Flowtype.js results in no change in actual font-size

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, typography

since this is  my first question asked - ever, I'd like to say thanks in advance because I have learned a lot through stackoverflow and it has helped me tons of times... Now the time has come to ask.

I discovered the concept of flowtype.js and liked it.
See here: http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/

I set up a local demo to play with, included all files (jquery,css,…) and started to look around why it is not functioning - which means: I looked for mistakes on my side, double checked, looked here on stackoverflow and found this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/FXL9k/2/

```
    $('body').flowtype({
    minimum   : 300,
    maximum   : 1200,
    minFont   : 10,
    maxFont   : 40,
    fontRatio : 30,
    lineRatio : 1.45
    });
```

In essence, this fiddle also shows the state I arrived at. To my understanding though the font size should change to a significant amount but stays unchanged, or to say it another way: it will not result into something beautiful like the demo page.

My Question now is: Am I missing something? How can I achieve the effect?
Many thanks in advance, again - this is really driving me insane.

Comment: be specific and make Your question simpler.

Comment: Sure! How do I get flowtype to work properly, since even the fiddle does not work as it should, to my understanding!? Thanks a lot for your helpful suggestion...